# Flutter - onUnknownRoute does not get triggered after using flutter build web

Tags: flutter, http-status-code-404, github-pages, flutter-web

So, I built a website using flutter web. Everything works fine when I run using flutter run command, the onUnknownRoute gets triggered when I type something in the URL that does not exist. But when I build my project using the flutter build web command, the onUnknownRoute never gets triggered. I have uploaded my project on github pages but onUnknownRoute never gets triggered. I don't even understand what the error could be so, I don't know what exactly should I be posting here as the error-prone code. I shall be delighted if I could get some help. Thank You.

The main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/constants.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/themeProvider.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/themeStyles.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/error404.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/getInTouch/getInTouch.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/mainSection.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/serviceDetails/serviceDetails.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/routeConfiguration.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ThemeProvider _themeProvider = ThemeProvider();

  void getCurrentAppTheme() async {
    _themeProvider.lightTheme = await _themeProvider.darkThemePref.getTheme();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentAppTheme();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'App',
        theme: ThemeStyles.themeData(_themeProvider.lightTheme, context),
        onGenerateRoute: RouteConfiguration.onGenerateRoute,
        initialRoute: MainPage.Route,
        onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
          return CustomPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => ErrorPage(),
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              settings: RouteSettings(name: ErrorPage.Route));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The routeConfiguration.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/error404.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/mainSection.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/Path.dart';

class RouteConfiguration {
  /// List of [Path] to for route matching. When a named route is pushed with
  /// [Navigator.pushNamed], the route name is matched with the [Path.pattern]
  /// in the list below. As soon as there is a match, the associated builder
  /// will be returned. This means that the paths higher up in the list will
  /// take priority.
  static List<Path> paths = [
    Path(
      r'^' + ErrorPage.Route + '\$',
      (context, match) => ErrorPage(),
    ),
    Path(
      r'^' + ErrorPage.Route + '/\$',
          (context, match) => ErrorPage(),
    ),
  ];

  /// The route generator callback used when the app is navigated to a named
  /// route. Set it on the [MaterialApp.onGenerateRoute] or
  /// [WidgetsApp.onGenerateRoute] to make use of the [paths] for route
  /// matching.
  static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == "/") {
      return CustomPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainPage(),
        settings: settings,
      );
    }
    for (Path path in paths) {
      final regExpPattern = RegExp(path.pattern!);
      if (regExpPattern.hasMatch(settings.name!)) {
        final firstMatch = regExpPattern.firstMatch(settings.name!);
        final match = (firstMatch!.groupCount == 1) ? firstMatch.group(1) : null;
        return CustomPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return path.builder(context, match);
          },
          settings: RouteSettings(name: ErrorPage.Route),
        );
      }
    }

    // If no match was found, we let [WidgetsApp.onUnknownRoute] handle it.
    return CustomPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => ErrorPage(),
        settings: RouteSettings(name: ErrorPage.Route));
  }
}

class CustomPageRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget Function(dynamic)? builder;
  final RouteSettings settings;

  CustomPageRoute({this.builder, required this.settings})
      : super(
            pageBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            ) =>
                builder!.call(context),
            transitionsBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child,
            ) =>
                FadeTransition(
                  opacity: animation,
                  child: ScaleTransition(
                    scale: Tween<double>(
                      begin: 0.5,
                      end: 1.0,
                    ).animate(
                      CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: animation,
                        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                ),
            settings: settings);
}
```

the error404.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:app/animations/glitchAnimation.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/themeProvider.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/mainSection.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/animatedUFO.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/star_field.dart';
import 'package:app/widget/adaptiveText.dart';
import 'package:mouse_parallax/mouse_parallax.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:seo_renderer/seo_renderer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/animations/entranceFader.dart';
import 'package:app/sections/navBar/navBarLogo.dart';

class ErrorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String Route = "/404";
  @override
  _ErrorPageState createState() => _ErrorPageState();
}

class _ErrorPageState extends State<ErrorPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  ThemeProvider _themeProviders = ThemeProvider();
  bool isPressed = false;
  bool _isScrollingDown = false;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  static const double idleSpeed = .2;
  static const int starAnimDurationIn = 4500;

  ValueNotifier<double> _speedValue = ValueNotifier(idleSpeed);

  late AnimationController _starAnimController;
  late Animation<double> _starAnimSequence;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = _themeProviders.scroll;
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        if (!_isScrollingDown) {
          _isScrollingDown = true;
          setState(() {});
        }
      }

      if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
        if (_isScrollingDown) {
          _isScrollingDown = false;
          setState(() {});
        }
      }
    });

    _starAnimController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: starAnimDurationIn),
      reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: starAnimDurationIn ~/ 3),
    );
    _starAnimController.addListener(() {
      _speedValue.value = _starAnimSequence.value;
    });

    //Create an animation sequence that moves our stars back, then forwards, then to rest at 0.
    //This will be played each time we load a detail page, to create a flying through space transition effect
    _starAnimSequence = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: idleSpeed, end: -2)
            .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut)),
        weight: 20.0,
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: -2, end: 20)
            .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut)),
        weight: 30.0,
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 20, end: 0)
            .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut)),
        weight: 50.0,
      )
    ]).animate(_starAnimController);

    super.initState();
    // WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    //   if (regExpBots.hasMatch(window.navigator.userAgent.toString()) && (globalKey.currentState != null)) {
    //     globalKey.currentState.openDrawer();
    //   }
    // });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _scrollController.removeListener(() {});
    _starAnimController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _themeProv = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    int starCount = 400;
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: double.maxFinite,
            child: ImageRenderer(
              alt: 'Background Image For Decoration',
              link: 'assets/logos/i8.jpg',
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/logos/i8.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 30.0,
              sigmaY: 30.0,
            ),
            child: Scaffold(
              key: globalKey,
              extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
              backgroundColor: _themeProv.lightTheme
                  ? Colors.white
                  : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
              appBar: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 860)
                  ? AppBar(
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                          color: _themeProv.lightTheme
                              ? Color(0xff1C1C28)
                              : Colors.white),
                      elevation: 0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      actions: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                context, MainPage.Route, (c) {
                              return false;
                            });
                          },
                          child: NavBarLogo(),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  : _appBarTabDesktop(_themeProv),
              body: Stack(
                children: [
                  ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
                    valueListenable: _speedValue,
                    builder: (context, value, child) {
                      //Scrolling star background
                      return StarField(starSpeed: value, starCount: starCount);
                    },
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 27.0),
                      child: ParallaxStack(
                        resetOnExit: true,
                        useLocalPosition: true,
                        referencePosition: 0.6,
                        dragCurve: Curves.easeIn,
                        resetCurve: Curves.bounceOut,
                        layers: [
                          ParallaxLayer(
                            yRotation: 0.80,
                            xRotation: 0.80,
                            xOffset: 90,
                            yOffset: 80,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Center(
                                  child: TextRenderer(
                                    text: GlithEffect(
                                      child: AdaptiveText(
                                        "404",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: _height * 0.1,
                                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: _height * 0.02,
                                ),
                                TextRenderer(
                                  text: AdaptiveText(
                                    "We searched as far as we could, but were unable to find the page you were looking for.\nSorry.",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                                      fontSize: _height * 0.02,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      height: 2.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar _appBarTabDesktop(ThemeProvider _themeProv) {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor:
          _themeProv.lightTheme ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      centerTitle: false,
      title: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 780
          ? EntranceFader(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              offset: Offset(0, -10),
              delay: Duration(seconds: 3),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainPage.Route,
                      (c) {
                    return false;
                  });
                },
                child: NavBarLogo(
                  height: 37.0,
                ),
              ))
          : EntranceFader(
              offset: Offset(0, -10),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              delay: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainPage.Route,
                      (c) {
                    return false;
                  });
                },
                child: NavBarLogo(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.065,
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I read in some other solution for a custom 404 page for github pages that I need a custom domain for it to work. So, is that what is causing my problem.

Comment: For flutter web, try navigator 2

Answer (score 1):

You should use Navigator v2 for web. it has more features and makes working with web routes very easy.